# Select item from many-to-many table that has all these details... proper solution?

Tags: php, mysql, count, many-to-many

(PHP/MySQL) Let me preface by saying that this works, and that I'm wondering if there's a cleaner way. This seems a bit... brutish? And I'm not known for my efficient coding. :-/

```
TABLE (many-to-many)
scenid   mapid
  AA      01
  AA      02
  AA      04
  BB      01
  BB      04
  CC      02
  CC      03
  CC      05
  DD      01
  DD      02
  DD      03
```

You are searching for scenarios that have ALL of these maps: 01, 02, 03
(having all + some others is ok)

My current method is to use this query:

```
SELECT scenid, COUNT(scenid) FROM `TABLE`
WHERE mapid IN ( 01, 02, 03 )
GROUP BY scenid ORDER BY COUNT(scenid) DESC, scenid ASC
```

Which would produce this list:

```
scenid  COUNT
  DD      3
  AA      2
  CC      2
  BB      1
```

Then, within PHP, I run a `while` loop that copies scenids to a new array so long as the `COUNT` is still `==` the total number of mapids (in this case, 3). This trims off all results that contain only some of the required maps.

Again, *this works.* But I'm still very new to MySQL & PHP (and they're my first steps into programming) so I'm always wondering if my "*works*" is another person's "*did you see that idiot just reinvent the wheel? **lulz***"

Is there a better way? Thank you for your time.

Comment: you cant become a good programmer if your afraid of what others might say about your code. everyone wrote shitcode at the beginning. trying to improve yourself is always a very good attitude.

Comment: If I was afraid what others would say, I'd never ask on StackOverflow, would I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query looks ok, but you could do the filtering in `SQL` using `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT scenid, COUNT(*)
FROM `TABLE`
WHERE mapid IN ( 01, 02, 03 )
GROUP BY scenid
HAVING COUNT(*) = 3
ORDER BY scenid ASC
```